# Expand/Collapse Columns in Protected Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, grouping, protected

I'm trying to create expand and collapse buttons in google sheets because google won't allow that functionality in protected sheets.

In a protected sheet I have this function for collapse:

```
function Collapse() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var range = sheet.getRange('D1:M1');
  sheet.setColumnGroupControlPosition(SpreadsheetApp.GroupControlTogglePosition.BEFORE);
 var user = Session.getActiveUser();
  sheet.protect().addEditor(user)
 var group = sheet.getColumnGroup(4, 1);
  group.collapse();
}
```

It's still not allowing other individuals to expand/collapse the columns.

Is there something I can do to allow users to access this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use a checkbox and an installed onEdit() trigger to allow anyone with access to show / hide the ranges.

```
 function Collapse(e) {

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  var range = e.range.getA1Notation();

  if(range == "A1" && sheetName == "Sheet1"){

  var value = sheet.getRange(range).getValue();   

    if(value){
      sheet.hideColumns(2, 4);
      sheet.hideRows(2,4);
    } else if (!value) {      
      sheet.showColumns(2, 4);
      sheet.showRows(2,4);
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample show / hide sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w5WsiYYS13DT-W2wbNvklRaf6OsroD0U10WQEbq-p00/edit?folder=0AKxyt5Qg-jB2Uk9PVA#gid=0)